# how to specify the connection string if the excel file name contains white space?using c#

Tags: c#

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\data\\[Proj_Resource Details 20110118.xlsx];Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

i mentioned [ ] still it is throwing exception.how can i solve this problem.
plz mention the correct path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the whole filename in quotes, but because this is a literal string use \" to escape them:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"D:\\data\\Proj_Resource Details 20110118.xlsx\";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it as just

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\data\\Proj_Resource Details 20110118.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

**without** the []s?

By the way, if you are not escaping anything, just use @

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\data\Proj_Resource Details 20110118.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

Answer (score 0):

string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=**\"**D:\data\Proj_Resource Details 20110118.xlsx**\";**Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";

Comment: It is working good.u can try the above syntax if your excel filename contains spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you still cannot connect or get "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine" error, you need to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255