# C# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll when attempting connect to excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, oledbconnection

I am trying to read data from Excel in C# without office installation.

My code

```
DataTable dTable;
DataTable dTable_Fixed;

string sProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= {0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
string sourceConstr = string.Format(sProvider.ToString(), file_name);

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(sourceConstr);
OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
con.Open();

DataTable dt1 = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

string firstExcelSheetName = dt1.Rows[0][2].ToString();
string query = "select * from [" + firstExcelSheetName + "]";
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
data.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Sheet1");
dTable = new DataTable();

data.Fill(dTable);
```

The connection was not established. I am getting an error log.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in
>   System.Data.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131547875442986389): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. Application Insights Telemetry
>   (unconfigured):
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev..,"ai.operation.name":"POST
>   FileDownload"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"9AAlQXMsrt4=","name":"POST
>   FileDownload","duration":"00:00:06.9290000","success":false,"responseCode":"500","url":"http://localhost:52087/api/FileDownload?Company_ID=CO_2005","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
>   The thread 0x3de0 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[19508]
>   chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff). The program
>   '[15740] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: Do you have the OleDb provider installed? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 I believe is what you’d use for that version.

Comment: Does `file_name` hold the full absolute path to the Excel file?

Comment: string file_name = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MassUploadFiles/Upload/" + Company_ID + ".xlsx"); This is my file path. It contains file.

Comment: The debug control will be stopped at the line of con.Open(); I didn't get any error.

Comment: @theoretical Yes, I have installed already.

Comment: @mjwills, Line : con.Open();

Comment: Might be the space before {0} in your connection string. Try using the `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` as described in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983973/problem-with-oledbconnection-string-folder-name-contain-white-space

Comment: @LocEngineer according to the docs, leading and trailing spaces are ignored. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx but inner spaces may be an issue?

Comment: Do you have the InnerException property set in your Exception? If yes what is the message of this InnerException?

Comment: It may help to check out **https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/**. There are many variations possible, including with version attributes for different Excel file formats.

Comment: I wrapped around try-catch block. Now I am getting "External table is not in the expected format." message. I am using Excel 2016

Comment: My connection string looks like : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sankaran\source\repos\AccountMapping_v2\AccountMapping_v2\MassUploadFiles\Upload\CO_2005.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES";

Comment: "Excel 2016" - now there seems to be the culprit. You probably need to install ACE: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255  See this thread here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/connection-string-access-2016/896ba075-7fcd-4be8-9f44-ec514b01cc11?auth=1

Comment: Yes Installed. Now I am getting "External table is not in the expected format" Error message

Comment: Have you gone for the obvious, i.e. checked whether it actually _is_ in the expected format? Open the file in Notepad++ or any other text editor. Does it start with PK ?

Comment: yes it starts with PK.

Comment: Funny. This thread says it could be a missing MSXML 6.0 package that needs to be installed: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57cb3121-755d-4cd5-8cda-a0630cbf535b/microsoftaceoledb120-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-error-on-windows-2003-server?forum=adodotnetdataproviders   Try installing MXSML 6.0 https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=6276