# What to do about spaces on my connection string?

Tags: c#, spaces

For example:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="\\na1b\uj\UP647529\Year 2\Managing Data and Security\Employee.accdb";
```

Visual studio won't let me run my program until I remove the spaces but thats where the database is..

How can I sort out that connection string to make Visual studio happy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849332/how-to-specify-the-connection-string-if-the-excel-file-name-contains-white-space

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like the problem is with the quotation marks in the string literal.

Try replacing each quote with two sets:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""\\na1b\uj\UP647529\Year 2\Managing Data and Security\Employee.accdb""";
```

Alternatively, you can ditch the literal and use escape characters:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"\\\\na1b\\uj\\UP647529\\Year 2\\Managing Data and Security\\Employee.accdb\"";
```

With all those backslashes in the file path, though, it can be a little hard to read.