# Parse string from app.config with characters that are escaped

Tags: c#, connection-string, sqlconnection, html-escape-characters

This is a really stupid question, but I'm getting really frustrated over it right now.

I have an app.config that store user credentials right now, for SQL Server.

So the username is reader and password is "abcdefg".

When i try to execute an insert now I get this exception:

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 138.

When I change the credentials to an user that doesn't have any special characters that has o be escaped it works like a charm.

Do anyone know what it can be?

The connection string that gets mashed up during a debug session is:

```
Data Source=MACHINE\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DbName;Connect Timeout=300;Application Name=application;User ID=reader;Password=\"abcdefg\"
```

Comment: I think this may have been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241862/what-to-do-about-spaces-on-my-connection-string

Comment: @jonaglon: That is what I did when I hard coded the password. But when I read it from app.config its a different matter. I can't add any .NET escape characters in the config since the value is stored within quotation marks. Then the app.config will be unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the double quotes in the password field with `&quot;`

So the connectionStrings would look like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=MACHINE\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DbName;Connect Timeout=300;Application Name=application;User ID=reader;Password=&quot;abcdefg&quot;" name="CS"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml character escaping. For instance a space is
    &#x20;
You can escape any character that way. The general form is
    &#x*hhhh*;
or
    &#*nnnn*;
where *hhhh* is hexadecimal and *nnnn* is decimal.

There are also 'shortcuts' listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references