# Not a Valid File name

Tags: c#

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Anybody can tell me what is the solution i just connect to the database and i am facing such type of error in pc while on my laptop its working perfectly.

the code is below

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\muhammad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\check1\check1\check.accdb;";


OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
con.Open();
label1.text="connected";
con.Close();
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849332/how-to-specify-the-connection-string-if-the-excel-file-name-contains-white-space

Comment: does your pc have that file path?

Comment: Why is the title "Not a Valid File name"? Is that part of an inner exception? If so, you should make sure you state that in the body of the question.

Comment: yes i copy the access file in the project file

Comment: You have spaces in your path.  try putting the filename in quotes.

Comment: like this???

con.ConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="c:\users\muhammad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\check1\check1\check.accdb;"";

Comment: @MuhammadTalha You have to delimit the double quotes inside of a verbatim string with another double quote like `@"Sally said, ""Hello""."`

Comment: just put your file in c:\downloads and try using that path.