# connection string error during deployment c#

Tags: c#

```
OleDbConnection MyConN= new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\3d_ServeR\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POS\POS\POSDb.accdb");
```

connection string error on program deployment
is there a fix on this problem?

tried but i think is this for sql only

```
OleDbConnection MyConN_Deploy = new OleDbConnection
    {
        ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\POSDb.accdb"
    };
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDkWB.png)

Comment: Any time you get a “connection string error” you need to [tell us what the error is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: It is quite odd to have the database in the same folder as the EXE since files in Program Files generally aren't editable by non-admin users.

Comment: Might be due to the spaces in the path; see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849332/how-to-specify-the-connection-string-if-the-excel-file-name-contains-white-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the correct path to your database file, something like this:

```
//If it's on the same folder as the executable then 
//you can set it to the file name without specifying a path.
var dbPath = "Path\\To\\Your\\DB\\POSDb.accdb";

OleDbConnection MyConN= new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dbPath}");
```